# Detaching by JPA CriteriaDelete with in-expression having subquery seems not executing properly

Tags: java, jpa, orm, spring-data

I need to delete some entities with specific field being in an other query with help of `CriteriaBuilder` & `CriteriaDelete`. hare is what i have tries so far.

```
CriteriaDelete<Y> criteriaDelete = criteriaBuilder.createCriteriaDelete(orphan);


Root<Y> deleteRoot = criteriaDelete.from(one_type);
Root<T> queryRoot = criteriaDelete.from(other_type);

criteriaQuery.select(queryRoot.get(key));

entityManager.createQuery(criteriaDelete
        .where(deleteRoot.in(entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery
                .where(queryRoot.get("id").in(givenList))).getResultList())));
```

Which `deleteRoot` stands for entity that i want to remove and `queryRoot` can be any associated entity with in main entity, which we seek for having criteria delete with in expression from that, after executing method that contains the shared snippet, no data will affected.

Comment: That doesn't look like a subquery at all - you are creating a query and executing it with the getResultList() call, have nothing defined for givenList, and provided nothing for the where clause to filter on within the criteriaQuery. What are you attempting, maybe try JPQL first "delete from Type t where t.id in (select id from <your where clause parameters>)", or even try using a select query instead of a delete query at first to verify you can get the subquery logic working with criteria api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respects of properly adding predicates based on aliases and query components, once should explicitly call the [executeUpdate](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) method on `javax.persistence.Query`

```
entityManager.createQuery(criteriaDelete
    .where(deleteRoot.in(entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery
            .where(queryRoot.get("id").in(givenList))).getResultList())));
```

Some thing like

```
entityManager.createQuery(...).executeUpdate();
```